# Ajax (partial view) in ASP.NET MVC 5 is not working - always open just partial view alone

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem that on click which should refresh just part of page (partial view) open new page only with "select" (that's the part that should be shown inside index page). I was trying do this with this tutorial http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.sk/2013/09/part-92-ajax-with-aspnet-mvc.html but I have no idea what's wrong - also I didn't find anything about it in this forum.

Resources in shared _Layout:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Inside Map/Index:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("All", "GetTracks",
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "GET", // HttpMethod to use, GET or POST
                    UpdateTargetId = "mytestdiv", // ID of the HTML element to update
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace // Replace the existing contents
                })

<div id="mytestdiv">
</div>
```

Map controller (and I know this is bad solution using just Viewbag - it's only temporary):

```
public PartialViewResult GetTracks()
{
    List<int> trackIDs = new List<int>();

    var queryTrack = from dTrack in db.track
                        where dTrack.device_id == 1
                        select dTrack.id;

    foreach (int trackId in queryTrack)
    {
        trackIDs.Add(trackId);
    }

    ViewBag.trackIDs = trackIDs;
    return PartialView("SelectTrackView");
}
```

And what I want to reload with Ajax, located in ~/Views/Map/SelectTrackView.cshtml:

```
<select id="SelectTrack" name="idTrack" class="form-control" style="margin:20px" onchange="selectTrack()">

    @foreach (int number in ViewBag.trackIDs)
    {
        if (ViewBag.selectedidTrack == @number)
        {
            <option value="@number" selected="selected">@number</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option value="@number">@number</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there any error in your browser javascript console ?

Comment: And also this is how final source code looks like:<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#mytestdiv" href="/Map/GetTracks">All</a>

<div id="mytestdiv">   
</div>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have a reference to jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js in your page ?

If not the data-* tags genererated by these helpers will not be interpred and the link will be considerated as "normal" links.

EDIT:

you need this package I think: [Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/).

if you do not want to use this package, simply put

```
<script>
(function($){
    $(document).on("click","a[data-ajax='true']", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#"+ $(this).attr("data-ajax-update")).load(this.href);
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: when I added `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>`, it was giving error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'unobtrusive' of undefined ". I'm really not sure - but `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` doesn't add unobstrusive? Because in my projects scripts I have this package added. But yes it's possible that it's not working like I was thinking it is.

Comment: Thanks, I had bad library from the beggining :-/ Really stupid mistake... When I downloaded Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax library   it started working properly. With `~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` it was'nt working at all :(. Thank You very much